# prove that the series $G \ (x)= \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{} \frac{f (x- r_n)}{2^n}$ almost always converge and

Tags: real-analysis

Friends can you help me with this demo? I really don't understand anything here.
Consider the function $f \ (x) = \frac{1}{√x}\chi (0,1)$ and let $(r_n)$ be an enumeration of the rationals, prove that the series

$G \ (x)= \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{} \frac{f (x - r_n)}{2^n}$ almost always converge and $G (x)$ is integrable in $\mathbb {R}$

Comment: Confusing question.  Are x and r supposed to be the same?

Comment: Hello, I just edited the exercise, can you help me with this demonstration please?